# SpriteKit custom subclass inside reference node init(coder:) called multiple times for single object

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

My SKScene (GameScene) is initialised from an '.sks' file called 'GameScene', which contains just an 'SKReferenceNode' to another sks file called 'Tank'
[image: GameScene.sks hierachy]

'Tank.sks' contains an SKNode which has the custom class 'Tank':

In the class definition for 'Tank' I defined 'init(coder:)' like so:

```
class Tank: SKNode {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        print("setup")
    }
}
```

**When I run the project, 'setup' is output three times** (even though there should only be one tank object').
I checked that there is only one Tank object like so:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    enumerateChildNodes(withName: "//*") { (node, _) in
        if node is Tank {
            print("found a tank")
        }
    }
}
```

but 'found a tank' is only printed once.

Why is this, and **is there another method I can use** to setup my 'Tank' which is only called once when the Object is unarchived and ready for use (similar to 'didMoveToView' for SKScene.

Comment: Sprite Kit makes a dummy SKScene object when first loading (I am assuming for caching purposes) Then it makes the actual object you need.  So you have 1 time for the GameScene sks, 1 time for the reference node sks, and then 1 time since you are actually using this last object

Comment: Thanks, so is there a method which is only called once when unarchiving which I can use to setup variables etc.?